# Magento Static block now showing up in CMS Page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, categories, display

Hy ! I'm trying to display the categories on a cms page.I've tried all the solution on the web but none is working for me. The last one i've tried is this.

1.I've added this code in content tab of my cms page : 
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/category/list.phtml"}}

2.I've created the list.phtml and put the file on app/design/theme-name/template/catalog/category.

Here is the code pf my file

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
    <?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
    <?php
    $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
    if ($immagine = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):
        ?>
        <div class="catalog-image">

            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $immagine ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()) ?>" width="313" height="151" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="left"><h2><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></h2></div>

        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: you have not provide category id in static block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this code in content tab of your cms page:

> {{block type="core/template" template="page/categories-list.phtml"}}

2. Create a file in the theme such "categories-list.phtml"

> path: app/design/**theme-name**/template/page/categories-list.phtml

In this file, write the following code in order to get a collection of all the categories:

```
<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addIsActiveFilter();
?>
```

If you want only some categories of parent, use the following code:

```
<?php
    $parent_category_id = 5;    // this is ID of parent category
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parent_category_id);
?>
```

To display categories on the screen, use loop, look below:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

    <p><?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you use the categories of the parent category to display the image, use the following code:

> `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getImageUrl();`

Comment: i did like you've said but isn't working. My magento version is 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder under catalog with name navigation and put your list.phtml file there it will work.

   {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/navigation/list.phtml" category_id="507" }}
2. Category Display Mode shuould be in static block in display setting.

Comment: i did like you've said but isn't working. My magento version is 1.9.2.2